# Intersection Observer API not working with hidden elements

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

I am trying to observe a hidden element. I have an element which has style set to `display: none`. I want when my element intersect it will perform my action i.e: Play the video. I am sharing my sample code below

```
 var options = {threshold: 0.5 }     

 var circle = document.getElementById('content_video');

 var observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
     var [{ isIntersecting }] = entries
     if (isIntersecting) {
         player.play();
         player.ima.getAdsManager().resume();
     } else {
         player.ima.getAdsManager().pause();
     }
 }, options);

 window.addEventListener('load', () => {
     if ('IntersectionObserver' in window) observer.observe(circle);
 }, false);
```

Comment: I am not sure, but if the element is empty you don't need a display:none.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is normal behaviour, because element with `display:none` cannot be reached and ignoring by browser

Try set other styles instead `display:none`. Example, use opacity or width and height 0 with overflow: hidden

Comment: Unfortunately if your goal is to use the intersection observer to lazy load the media, this will not fulfill the purpose since the media will load before it intersects with the viewport :/

Comment: The opacity 0 was a good tip, thanks. I have a scroll area with overflow hidden so the scrolling area stays a fixed height. It looks like the intersection observer doesn't trigger until my target element enters scroll window. the rootMargin isn't working. any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately if your goal is to use the intersection observer to lazy load the media, the answer will not fulfil the purpose since the media will load before it intersects with the viewport. The solution is to make sure it is the containing element of the media that is being observed, instead the element on which display none is being applied.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-lazyload-forked-yz93f?file=/src/LazyLoad.js:0-958

```
import React, { Component, createRef } from "react";

import "./styles.css";

class LazyLoad extends Component {
  observer = null;
  rootRef = createRef();
  state = {
    intersected: false
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      (entries) => {
        const entry = entries[0];
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
          this.setState({ intersected: true });
          this.observer.disconnect();
        }
      },
      { root: null, threshold: 0.2 }
    );
    this.observer.observe(this.rootRef.current);
    console.log(this.rootRef);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="outer" ref={this.rootRef}>
        <span>{JSON.stringify(this.state.intersected)}</span>
        <div
          className={`container ${
            this.state.intersected ? "d-block" : "d-none"
          }`}
        >
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LazyLoad;
```